# Compare tables of two PostgreSQL Databases with PK and FK

Tags: postgresql

I need to compare two PostgreSQL databases with exactly one SQL-query. I tried with the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name IN (SELECT table_name 
                     FROM information_schema.tables 
                     WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
                       AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
                     ORDER BY table_schema, TABLE_NAME);
```

It works for my problem but the foreign and primary keys are missing in this table. Is there are way to include them into my sql-query?

It is ok if the result table is not normalized and displays data multiple times. It is purely a runtime comparison, which is why the result tables are deleted again when the program has run through.

Comment: I don't understand how that is supposed to "compare" anything. It simply lists all columns in the current database. (Note that the sub-select is completely useless, you can apply that `where` condition directly on `information_schema.columns`)

Comment: I use this query on two databases. Then I compare the resulttable of these two queries. If it is the same, the databases have the same columns/PK/FK. Its for educational purposes to check if a learners database is correct.